# Not detecting height and width change for applet run via window.open()

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, applet

I created a clock applet that resizes the text as the user stretches the window around.  In Netbeans it works fine but running the jar on the web server it does not detect any changes in size.  I initially was using getWidth() and getHeight() in the paint function to get the current window size.  When I realized it wasn't detecting changes outside of Netbeans I switched/add a componentResized() listener but that also doesn't detect any resizing outside of Netbeans either.

On the web server index.html page I am using win=window.open(url, name, the_size) to open a window with the clock applet inside.  Why is the listener not seeing any resizing as I stretch the window around?  Is it because window.open() window is different from the Netbean pop up window somehow?

```
   @Override
    public void init() {

        if (getParameter("verbose") != null)
        {
            try {
                m_verboseLevel = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("verbose"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " verbose: " + getParameter("verbose") + " is not 0->3");
                m_verboseLevel = 0;
             }
        }

        m_size = getParameter("size");
        m_clock_color = getParameter("color");

        // Add listener to update width and height as user changes it
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                  m_w = getWidth();
                  m_h = getHeight();
System.out.println(m_w + " "  + m_h);
            }
         });
        try {
```

In paint the m_w and m_h are initially 0 since since nothing has moved.  I call getWidth() and getHeight() and the output matches the html applet width and height values 600 and 800.  But outside of Netbeans m_h/m_w never changes so the scale logic doesn't change anything.

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // first time?
        if ((m_w == 0) && (m_h == 0)) {
            m_w = getWidth();     // return the width of the applet
            m_h = getHeight();    // return the height of the applet
        }

        // Use buffering for smooth update
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(m_w, m_h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2d);

        String[] lines = new String[2];
        lines[0] = "Acquisition of Signal";
        lines[1] = "Loss of Signal";

        // first time?
        if (m_clockLine == 0) {
            FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
            LineMetrics metrics = m_clock_font.getLineMetrics(lines[1], frc);

            // Omitt the descent from the height variable.
            String time = "00:00:00";
            g2d.setFont(m_clock_font);
            float height1 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_width = m_clock_font.getStringBounds(time, frc).getWidth();
            m_clockLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            metrics = m_label_font.getLineMetrics(lines[0], frc);
            float height2 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_labelLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            metrics = m_tk_font.getLineMetrics(lines[1], frc);
            float height3 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_titleLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            m_width += 22*2;
            m_height = height1 + height2 + height3 + height1 + height2 + (m_padding*4);
        }
System.out.println(m_w + " " + m_width +  " " + m_h +  " " + m_height);

        g2d.scale(m_w/m_width, m_h/m_height);

        /* Make background black */
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int)m_width, (int)m_height);

         /* Draw individual clock labels */
        g2d.setFont(m_label_font);
        g2d.setColor(m_main_color);

        g2d.drawString(lines[0], 145, m_clockLine+m_labelLine+m_padding);
        g2d.drawString(lines[1], 220, m_clockLine+m_labelLine+m_titleLine+m_clockLine+m_labelLine+(m_padding*4));

        // Write check clock timer lines
        if (m_c != null) {
            m_c.print(g2d, m_labelLine, m_clockLine, m_titleLine, m_padding, m_width, m_height);
        }

        g2d.dispose();
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    } // end paint
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of googling I found out what the problem is.  When the applet is checking it's dimensions either using the addComponentListener componentResized or the getWidth/getHeight call it is reading the html width and height values for the applet/object.  When using the Netbeans Applet Viewer these values are being changed as the viewer is being stretched.  But in a html page the width and height are not changing as the browser is resized.  This is why the applet size doesn't change when you stretch the browser.  So the solution in the real environment is reset the width and height values via javascript so that the applet can see the new dimensions onLoad.  Note: onResize doesn't seem to ever go off but I left it in anyway.

So I removed the componentResized logic and in the paint function just call getWidth/getHeight for the applet dimensions.  This is the final paint function.

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // This makes the applet resizable
        int w = getWidth();     // return the width of the applet
        int h = getHeight();    // return the height of the applet

        // Use buffering for smooth update
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2d);

        String[] lines = new String[2];
        lines[0] = "Acquisition of Signal";
        lines[1] = "Loss of Signal";

        // first time?
        if (m_clockLine == 0) {
            FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
            LineMetrics metrics = m_clock_font.getLineMetrics(lines[1], frc);

            // Omitt the descent from the height variable.
            String time = "00:00:00";
            g2d.setFont(m_clock_font);
            float height1 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_width = m_clock_font.getStringBounds(time, frc).getWidth();
            m_clockLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            metrics = m_label_font.getLineMetrics(lines[0], frc);
            float height2 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_labelLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            metrics = m_tk_font.getLineMetrics(lines[1], frc);
            float height3 = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent();
            m_titleLine = (int) (metrics.getAscent() - 1);

            m_width += 22*2;
            m_height = height1 + height2 + height3 + height1 + height2 + (m_padding*4);
        }

        g2d.scale(w/m_width, h/m_height);

        /* Make background black */
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int)m_width, (int)m_height);

         /* Draw individual clock labels */
        g2d.setFont(m_label_font);
        g2d.setColor(m_main_color);

        g2d.drawString(lines[0], 145, m_clockLine+m_labelLine+m_padding);
        g2d.drawString(lines[1], 220, m_clockLine+m_labelLine+m_titleLine+m_clockLine+m_labelLine+(m_padding*4));

        // Write check clock timer line
        if (m_c != null) {
            m_c.print(g2d, m_labelLine, m_clockLine, m_titleLine, m_padding, m_width, m_height);
        }

        g2d.dispose();
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    } // end paint
```

In the html script I added the following logic:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <TITLE>Terra Small Clock</TITLE>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.17842">
  </head>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    /*
    Description:
    The re-size function job is to reset the applet width and height to the new dimensions as the 
    user stretches the browser window.  The clock applet will then use the "current" width and 
    height to scale the clock.
    */
    function resize()
    {
       if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1)
       {
          // 100% works fine on object tag with IE
          return;
       }
       var w_newWidth,w_newHeight;

       var netscapeScrollWidth=0;
       w_newWidth  = window.innerWidth-netscapeScrollWidth;
       w_newHeight = window.innerHeight-netscapeScrollWidth;

       var appletDiv = document.getElementById('clockApp');
       if (appletDiv != null) {
         appletDiv.style.width  = w_newWidth  + "px";
         appletDiv.style.height = w_newHeight + "px";
       }
    }

    window.onResize = resize;
    window.onLoad   = resize;
  </SCRIPT>
  <body bgcolor="000000" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" onResize="resize()" onLoad="resize()">
    <p style="text-align:center">
      <object type="application/x-java-applet" id="clockApp" width="240" height="230">
        <param name="codebase" value="https://<host stuff>.nasa.gov/java_clocks/classes/" />
        <param name="code" value="aosClock.class" />
        <param name="archive" value="clock.jar" />

        <param name="verbose" value="0" />
        <param name="color" value="green" />
        <param name="input_file" value="https://<host stuff>.nasa.gov/java_clocks/terra/terra_aos_times" />
      </object>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when I stop stretching the browser window the onLoad goes off and the applet/object width and height are reset.  The applet then scales the clock for the new dimensions.